# Asymptotic Notations: doubling size of input and changes in running time

Tags: calculus, limits, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I am trying to learn and understand Asymptotic Notation. I used MIT ocw course 6.042 as my resource.

in this course the teacher said:

> the elementary algorithm takes order O of n cubed steps. And that's
> the important fact. And it tells you that if you double the size of
> the matrix the running time will increase by at most a factor of eight
> in the limit as n gets large.

How does this fact that the algorithm takes order O of n cubed steps tell us that if we double the size of the matrix, the running time will increase by at most a factor of 8 in the limit? which limit is he talking about?

actually I know this: $T(n) = O (n^3)$   and if I double the size of input, I have: $T(2n) = O (8n^3)$ but he is talking about a limit. I want to understand that what's happened in that limit.

could you please explain about this paragraph? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is as $n$ gets very large.  It is true that $n^3+1000000n^2 \in O(n^3)$ but for $n \lt 1000000$ the second term will be greater than the first.  If we double from $n=10$ to $n=20$ the value of the expression is multiplied by about $4$, not $8$, because the second term is dominating.  When $n$ is large enough the $n^3$ term will dominate and the cubic behavior will be the important one.  Here that is when $n$ is rather larger than $1000000$.

Comment: actually I understood all of your answer except the first sentence. ***The limit is as n gets very large.*** what does it mean? 

and my second question: according to this sentence of teacher (that he said *the running time will increase by at most a factor of eight in the limit as n gets large.*), I expected to see a particular limit like this: $\lim_{x \to +\infty} |\frac{\Box}{\Box}|$. and actually my question was because of this purpose. to see the limit expression. So he did not mean a specific limit expression?

Comment: You could write it $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {T(2n)}{T(n)}=8$  but we usually do not.  We just say the dominant term is of order $n^3$

Comment: and what does it mean? **The limit is as n gets very large.**

Comment: It means that $n$ is large enough that the leading term in the expression dominates, however large that has to be.